# Python No such file or directory

Tags: python, path

```py
import json

with open("data.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

print(data)
```

Thats the py code.

```json
{
    "test":"Hi"
    "things": [
        {
            "name":"Stack"
            "lastname":"Overflow"
        }
    ]
}
```

That's the JSON file.

The JSON and python file are in the same folder and I don't get it why it does not find the file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you are not running the script from the directory where these files are present.

Attempt 1:

You can try to run the script from the same directory as those files and it should work.

Attempt 2:

You can use the absolute path of the `json` file instead of just specifying the file name.
You can modify your code like this :

```
import json
from os import path

file_path = path.abspath(__file__) # full path of your script
dir_path = path.dirname(file_path) # full path of the directory of your script
json_file_path = path.join(dir_path,"data.json") # absolute file path of json file


with open(json_file_path, "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

print(data)
```